# UINavigationBar mysteriously disappears in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I started a project with Xcode 4, and today I updated my Xcode to 5. Running the same project in iOS7 simulator revealed some interesting (also frustrating) issues.

So my app has a sidebar that the user can tap on, and based on which button they tap on, I would instantiate a new VC using this code

```
YMGeneralInfoTableViewController *generalInfoTableVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"generalInfoTableVC"];
```

Then push this new VC onto the nav stack with this code

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:generalInfoTableVC animated:YES];
```

Everything worked fine in iOS 6. However, in iOS7, the navbar magically disappears.

Here's a screen shot before pushing new VC
[image]

Here is after pushing it:
[image]

As you can see, there is a gap between where the content starts and the statusBar, in the position where the navBar should be.

I also tested out this code again on my iOS 6 device, everything is still fine on that iOS 6 device. So I am not sure what's going on here.

Also if I try to log the navBar/navigationItem of the controller where the navbar disappeared, I do get the correct reference to the navBar, which means that it is not nil, but simply not showing.

However, the method`setHideNavigationBar:NO Animated:NO` didn't bring the navBar back either. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Are those screenshots supposed to be cut off, or is that directly from the simulator?

Comment: yeah sorry I only captured part of the simulator, so yes they're supposed to be cut off.

Comment: Oh okay, I could hardly see the contrast from the nav bar and wondering what else I was missing. I see it now.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I actually found a temporary solution which just involves setting navBar.translucent = NO. But this leads to other issues as well, eg. my custom menu icon is not showing.

Comment: try to toggle the translucency of navigation bar.     self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; // YES

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I've found the solution for this.

It is because in AppDelegate, you might already set some of appearance changes for the Navigation Bar.

So what I suggest you to do is to check the device OS first before set custom apperance for Navigation Bar?

```
- (BOOL)isOS7
{
    float currentVersion = 7.0;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < currentVersion)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

So if return "NO" then only you do whatever possible that can be use for

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Autolayout constraints,

I have tried same by using iOS 6 and iOS 7, my navigation bar is showing. Still checkout Autolayout constraints, i have doen it without autolayout

Comment: I have disabled autolayout and it still behaves this way.